# I tried linking my JavaScript file to my html file but nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, html

I made an html file and I wanted to pass input from it into a function in a separate JavaScript file and then have it add it to a sql server. The JavaScript file works when I run it alone but when I try to call it from my html file by clicking a button nothing happens. I checked the console and there don't appear to be any errors and the other methods that I tried on stack overflow didn't work either

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>University Sign Up</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("img/SignUp.png");
            background-size: 100%;
        }
        
        h1 {
            color: #FFFF;
            font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: x-large;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        p {
            color: #FFFF;
            font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: medium;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        form {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>University Sign Up</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Whats is the name of your University?</p>
    <label> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" spellcheck="true" size="100" />
    <p id="error1"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>What is the email of the primary user of this account?</p>
    <label> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" size="100" />
    <p id="error2"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>What is the email url of you school (ie if your students email is example@student.edu put "student.edu")?</p>
    <label> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</label>
    <input type="text" id="url" size="100" />
    <p id="error3"></p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Please make a password that you can remember</p>
    <label> &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp; &emsp;</label>
    <input type="text" id="pass" size="100" />
    <p id="error4"></p>
    <form id="form">

        <button id="button" onclick="insertUniversity(document.getElementById('name').getAttribute('value'), document.getElementById('user').getAttribute('value'), document.getElementById('pass').getAttribute('value'), document.getElementById('url').getAttribute('value'))">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tested the function to see if it worked by calling it in the app.js file but I commented it out when I was trying to call it through the html file I also had a hard time printing out error messages to the user. When I was testing the function I made sure it worked by printing to console but it says that the function that I saw in examples aren't defined so. Also, on a lesser note I'm kind of new to JavaScript and html and any tips of cleaning up my code (ie helping me center the text box so I can get rid of all the &emsp or making it less redundant) would be greatly appreciated as well. Thanks!

```
function insertUniversity(name, email, password, url) {
    var idk = email.toLowerCase();
    var lowurl = url.toLowerCase();
    const mysql = require('mysql');

    // First you need to create a connection to the database
    // Be sure to replace 'user' and 'password' with the correct values
    const con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'sample',
        user: 'sample',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'dbo'
    });

    con.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error connecting to Db');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connection established');
    });

    if (name == null) {
        //document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "You are missing the name of your university";
        console.log("missing info");
        con.end((err) => {
            // The connection is terminated gracefully
            // Ensures all remaining queries are executed
            // Then sends a quit packet to the MySQL server.
        });
        return;
    }

    if (email == null) {
        //document.getElementById("error2").innerHTML = "You are missing a primary email";
        console.log("missing info");
        con.end((err) => {
            // The connection is terminated gracefully
            // Ensures all remaining queries are executed
            // Then sends a quit packet to the MySQL server.
        });
        return;
    }

    if (password == null) {
        //document.getElementById("error3").innerHTML = "You are missing a password";
        console.log("missing info");
        con.end((err) => {
            // The connection is terminated gracefully
            // Ensures all remaining queries are executed
            // Then sends a quit packet to the MySQL server.
        });
        return;
    }

    if (url == null) {
        //document.getElementById("error4").innerHTML = "You are missing a student url";
        console.log("missing info");
        con.end((err) => {
            // The connection is terminated gracefully
            // Ensures all remaining queries are executed
            // Then sends a quit packet to the MySQL server.
        });
        return;
    }

    con.query(`SELECT * FROM university WHERE university.userId='${name}';`, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(rows.length);
        if (rows.length > 0) {
            con.destroy((err) => {
                // The connection is terminated gracefully
                // Ensures all remaining queries are executed
                // Then sends a quit packet to the MySQL server.
            });
            return;
        } else {
            var str = `INSERT INTO university (userID, email, pass, url) VALUES ('${name}', '${idk}', '${password}','${lowurl}');`;
            con.query(str, (err, rows) => {
                if (err) throw err;

                console.log('Data inserted into Db:');
                console.log(rows);
            });
        }

    });


}
```

Comment: Just to limit the potential issues, I would try adding `type="button"` to your submit button. Since it is in a form, the default function of it is to submit that form.

Comment: get name, email, password, url inside of function instead of passing to function

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the code you posted in your browser. You need a Node.js Server for that. `require()` doesn't work in Vanilla JS. It would also be a bad idea to have your MySQL-credentials in plaintext like you have. Anyone could see them.

I would suggest you start looking into Node.js tutorials.